# Create a Workflow for email notification using SharePoint 2010

Tags: email, sharepoint-2010, notifications, workflow

I had to create a workflow to create an email notification every time the content is modified.
The Email should go to a specified set of owners and a publisher.Can anyone walk me through the steps?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create workflow in SharePoint designer 2010 and set the workflow start options when item is edited. In the workflow designer from workflow commands double click on email and configure it.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx